# How to recover these files when their filenames are changed to " #U4e09#U661f#U4ee5#U.."?

Tags: wordpress, filenames

My Wordpress site is recently moved, and later I found the image filenames are changed to this kind of filename:

```
 #U4e09#U661f#U4ee5#U..
```

They are used to be filename in Chinese. Somehow they are changed to this kind of filename and I don't really know the reason (besides, I don't have the old files because I changed server and old files are deleted)

Now these images cannot be loaded in my posts. Is there any method to make it work?

Comment: Do you still have the files on your server? I suspect the filenames are just encoded unicode strings, so the file _names_ can probably be restored, but if you don't have the files, there's no point in doing so. If you do have the files, consider renaming the files and filenames to a Latin character set - it'll make it easier!

Comment: These files are on the server. But their filenames are changed to this kind and the existing posts cannot recognize these filenames.

Comment: How many files are affected? If it's a low number, then rename them on the server (via SSH or FTP)? Presumably you can work out from your posts (and by viewing the images manually) which should be which? I'd recommend renaming them to meaningful names in a Latin charset, and then editing each post as well (but that might be a lot of work if you have many files).

Comment: @halfer There are too many files, and it's impossible to "identify" them one by one. Thanks for your replies. The Perl script from the Answer actually works to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Perl script *might* work, but only if your file system uses UTF-8 encoding for file names. Give it a try anyway:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# 
# Rewrite UTF-16 codes in file names
# Usage: fixutf.pl <directory>
# (Defaults to current directory if omitted)
# 

use strict;
use warnings;
my $oldname;
my $newname;
my $directory = '.';

binmode(STDOUT,':raw:encoding(UTF-8)');
if ($ARGV[0]) {
   $directory = $ARGV[0];
}
opendir (DIR,$directory) or die $!;
print "Scanning directory '$directory/' ...\n";

while ($oldname = readdir(DIR)) {
   if ($oldname =~ /#U([0-9a-f]{4})/) {
      $newname = $oldname;
      $newname =~ s/#U([0-9a-f]{4})/pack('U',hex($1))/seg;
      rename $oldname,$newname;
      print "  Renamed $oldname to $newname\n";
   }
}

print "Finished\n";
```

Save this as "fixutf.pl", change its permissions to `0755`, and then either run it from inside the directory that contains all your files, or pass the path to this directory as a command line argument. Please back your files up first, and be aware that the renaming process will overwrite any files of the same name if they exist in the same directory.

Comment: one more question tho, why using "ls", these filenames show "??????" instead. But they can be loaded by the Wordpress posts.

Comment: It means your terminal is having trouble displaying Unicode characters. On some systems you can fix this by typing in `export LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"` at the command line. (If it works, add this line to `.profile` in your home directory.) I can't guarantee it will work on your system, though.